# In Jquery, I want to bind some buttons in a loop but failed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can `alert` each button's id by doing so.

```
$(function () {
  bind_button();
});
function bind_button() {
  var len = $(".btn-sm").length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i ++ ){
    alert($(".btn-sm")[i].id);
  }
}
```

But when I want to bind the button with its id...

```
$(function () {
  bind_button();
});
function bind_button() {
  var len = $(".btn-sm").length;
  for(var i = 0; i < len; i ++ ){
    $(".btn-sm")[i].click(function (){
      alert($(".btn-sm")[i].id);
    });
  }
}
```

When I click the button, no alert appears.

Anyone knows why? And anyone knows how can I bind successfully?

Comment: That's because you add click listener on a javascript element and not a jquery.... when you access a $(".btn-sm")[i], with brackets, the return type is element and not jquery.

Comment: Oh, now I know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print only the id of the clicked button just do something like

```
function bind_button() {
   $(".btn-sm").click(function(){
      alert(this.id);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you need the loop at all. Why not get the buttons, and assign listeners to them all at once?

Note: I've used data attributes in this example.

```js
$(function () {
  $('.btn-sm').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).data('id'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn-sm" data-id="1">1</button>
<button class="btn-sm" data-id="2">2</button>
<button class="btn-sm" data-id="3">3</button>
<button class="btn-sm" data-id="4">4</button>
<button class="btn-sm" data-id="5">5</button>
```